# Crash while calling method in requestFinished method?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, crash

When I am calling [self MethodName] from any other methods, its working.

But while calling in "requestFinished", its crashes.

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{

    [self MethodName];  
}
```

[ClassName MethodName] - message sent to deallocated instance.

Any suggestions.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

**Your object (self) is released before the asynchronous call to requestFinished is executed**.

Check whether you keep a reference to the object around long enough - if you create the object without keeping a reference, it will be released at the end of the cycle, and when the requestFinished method is called later the object does not exist anymore.

Comment: You are champ. Can you tell what will I do then to solve this?

Comment: you should self retain when start , then you finish or failed, release again

Comment: or make the object a class variable of a class that will still exist, like your view controller or a singleton

Comment: How could the invocation of `-requestFinished:` have succeeded but not the invocation of `-MethodName`? @dilip.ajm, is this really an invocation `self`? Or is there code before the `[self MethodName]` line that you've left out that may be releasing the object itself?

Comment: Well, he probably just called requestFinished right away while his object is still existing, whereas normally it is called asynchronously when the request did finish (hence the name :-) - at that point the object did not exist anymore.